# Propel Nested Set in combination with Pagination

Tags: pagination, propel, nested-sets

```php
$root = AnimeCommentQuery::create()->findRoot(2);
$html = "<ul>{$root->getComment()}";

foreach ($root->getDescendants() as $post)
{
  $html .= '<li style="padding-left: '.$post->getLevel().' em;">';
  $html .= $post->getComment();
  $html .= ' by '.$post->getIbfMembersRelatedByInsertBy()->getName();
  $html .= "</li>";
}

$html .= "</ul>";
echo $html;
```

I want to paginate the posts but I am not able to do this by:

```
$root = AnimeCommentQuery::create()->findRoot(2)->paginate(2, 1);
```

OR

```
$root = AnimeCommentQuery::create()->paginate(2, 1)->findRoot(2);
```

Can it be done with standard Pagination from propel? And how?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is too late....

First off, you can't use the paginate and find in the same query, they're both termination methods.

I think what you need is something like this:

```
$comments = AnimeCommentQuery::create()->inTree(2)->orderByBranch()->paginate(2,1);
```

Then `foreach` your way through that `Collection`.

Now you'll have to be a bit clever with when to close and open lists, checking current Level etc. And top and bottom of page 2+ will take a bit of consideration too. Good Luck!

The Nested Set API is worth studying further http://www.propelorm.org/behaviors/nested-set.html#complete_api, got a fair bit in.

Also consider using a `->joinWith()` to get your `getIbfMembersRelatedByInsertBy()` prepopulated in the main query.